# Facebook authentication callback never called when not on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, oauth

I am using facebook for authentication. It works fine as long as my site is on localhost. But once i test on actual web server with proper domain name the callback from facebook is never called.

Using fiddler i can see i send this request to facebook:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1&client_secret=&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2FUser%2FFacebookCallback/%2F&response_type=code&scope=email

But my callback on mvc controller called FacebookCallback is never called. HTTPS is enabled and traffic goes through. Also everything works when using test environment with localhost.

Please help! I am going crazy...

Answer:

thank you, the problem turned out to be i was testing using proxy browser cause my router would not allow same external ip inside of my LAN. So a callback url was blocked. Simple silly issue with router... Thank you it is helpful to talk to somebody

Comment: Do you really have `/%2F` at the end of your `redirect_uri` parameter – one URL-encoded slash, preceded by a not encoded one? Maybe that’s what trips up your controller …

Comment: thank you for suggestion, it tried with and without, it doesn't work.

Comment: my current suspicion is that maybe facebook doesn't want to call me back on my URL because SSL is incorrectly setup. I use developer SSL certificate on my web site. Maybe facebook calls me back when using localhost and developer SSL certificate but not when i use real ip and developer SSL certificate.

Comment: This is not a “callback”, this part of the login process happens only in the browser – user gets send to the login dialog, confirms it, and gets redirected back to your URL … so at this point, Facebook doesn’t care at all about whether you have SSL set up correctly or not. (If not, only your browser would complain.)

Comment: you are right, when i redirect to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?.... the reply is code 404 when using real redirect_uri web site parameter, but it pops up standard facebook page when i use localhost as redirect_uri parameter. So i should shift my attention from my callback not called to why facebook returns undescriptive 404 message. Is there a way to know what facebook does with my call?

Comment: I doubt that this 404 is from Facebook – more likely it happens after you get redirected back to your `redirect_uri`, which means the 404 comes from _your_ server (/your app), because you either specified a wrong URL, or your routing does not handle it correctly.

Comment: the strangest part if i copy paste value of redirect_uri parameter in my browser then my callback is called, so it is reachable from browser, but navigating to it from facebook obviously fails. so i need to still continue probably my research in direction of SSL certificates

Comment: When the redirect to your URL happens, it will of course not be that exact same URL, but Facebook will attach additional GET parameters to it (like the `state` value and the `code` that can then be exchanged for an access token) – likely your application is not handling that correctly.

Comment: that is exactly the point, unfortunately i don't know what manipulations facebook does with my redirect_uri cause i never receive the callback call from facebook(i use network monitor to see what comes in and out)

Comment: What URL does your browser address bar show when you see the 404 error message?

Comment: thank you, the problem turned out to be i was testing using proxy browser cause my router would not allow same external ip inside of my LAN. So a callback url was blocked. Simple silly issue with router... Thank you it is helpful to talk to somebody.

Comment: Please update this StackOverflow question with the answer you found. Otherwise people will have to read this whole conversation to find the solution.